# How to shift page number of the section to the left side in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting

I would like to shift the page numbers of the section on the left side in the table of contents, as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what document class you intend to use.  Even better would be a small compilable example that can be used for experimentation.

Comment: The good news is that the page number is passed to \l@section as a separate argument.  The section number is formatted using \numberline   Is "Section A" the title or simply the section number?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm using document class tstextbook

Comment: the cls is available at -- https://www.typesetters.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tstextbook.cls  -- one of the experts will require to modify the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may point you in the right direction :

The imperative portion is

```
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}{\contentspage\hspace*{2.3em}}
{}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{}
```

taken from page 15-16 of the documentation of the `titletoc` package

[image]
[image]

The `\contentspage` compiles the page number and instead of placing it at the end of the section numbering environment, it is now placed at the beginning of the environment

The output :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}{\contentspage\hspace*{2.3em}}
{}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{a}
\cleardoublepage 
\section{section a}
\cleardoublepage
\section{section b}
\chapter{b} 
\cleardoublepage
\section{mysection}
\lipsum[4-10]
\section{mysection}
\chapter{c} 
\end{document}
```